# How do you prepend to std::stringstream?

Tags: c++

```
std::stringstream ss;

int number = 0x12345678;

ss << std::hex << number;

cout << ss.str();
```

This will produce `12345678`

I want to make it as `0x12345678`. How can I prepend `0x` in front of `ss.str()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probably simplest way to do this is to change the formatting of the `stringstream ss`: Make it automatically prepend the number base with [`std::showbase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    int number = 0x12345678;

    ss << std::showbase << std::hex << number; // prepends the 0x automagically

    std::cout << ss.rdbuf(); // empties ss
}
```

Note that I changed the output from `cout << ss.str()` to `cout << ss.rdbuf()`. This modifies the stream `ss` (it is empty afterwards), but requires no copy as in the OP's example.

Once you've put the number into the stringstream, there's no simple way I know of to prepend the `0x` *in this stringstream*. You could then however print it before printing the contents of the stream to `cout`:

```
std::cout << "0x" << ss.rdbuf();
```